# Variable captured before being initialised, error after migration to Swift 2

Tags: json, initialization, migration, nsdictionary, swift2

I'm having a problem after migrating my code to swift 2 (I'm very new at Swift and programming for iOS in general, so it might be a stupid mistake)

Because of the error handling in Swift 2 I added a "do, try ,catch" clause for my data retrieval:

Before:

```
jsonData: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!,
    options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary}
```

After:

```
do{
    try jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!,
    options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary} 

catch let errorParsing as NSError
     {errorParsing.description}


let success:NSInteger = jsonData!.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger
```

But now every time I try to access the jsonData object (example in the last line of code) I get the error "Variable captured by a closure before being initialised"

Can anyone explain to me how I can fix this, I tried using 'init()' but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: I know some other people here already posted a question about the same error, but none of them contained information/fix I could use.

Kr,

Answer (score 0):

Use jsonData inside the `do { }`.

```
do{
    let try jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!,
    options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
} 

   let success:NSInteger = jsonData!.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

catch let errorParsing as NSError
     {errorParsing.description}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I still got an error when I added the "let" in front of my try clause, but I changed the do, try, catch to a higher level in the code and now it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is no need to declare additional NSError variable. You can just put the code like that:

```
do{
    try jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!,
    options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary} 

catch {
    fatalError(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I removed the NSError variable out of my code.